# C# - Stretching a textbox to fit the containing window

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, resize

I want the text box to stay a certain distance from the top, bottom, left, and right edges of the parent form, and to stretch as the window does.

Currently I have:

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width - 24, richTextBox1.Size.Height);
}
```

...for the width, but I'm wondering if that's the right way or not. Is there a better way?

Comment: Place the textbox where you want it on the form and set the Anchor property to Top, Bottom, Left, and Right.

Comment: @Mooz,  add this as an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @Moozhe, I'll accept it as the answer if you put it there :D

Comment: I hate giving one line answers.  If I answer I feel obligated to provide sample code and a long explanation of the wonderful world of Docking and Anchoring and margins.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Moozhe said you need [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of the control

> Use the Anchor property **to define how a control is automatically
>   resized as its parent control is resized.** Anchoring a control to its
>   parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same
>   position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent
>   control is resized.

But also from my experience do not forget to assign `MinimumSize` and
 `MaximumSize` of the control these properties helps for the control to have certain minimum or maximum size if you resize your form too small or too big.

Answer (score 10):

you can also use **Dock** property like so:

```
richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
richTextBox1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right |  AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);
```